# Client found response content type of 'multipart/related

Tags: c#, web-services, mtom

I am using a web service to process data. And as it seems to me I’m sending request properly. I added web references from wsdl  and  add an secure token. But when I’m try to get response it throws the following error:

> Invalid Operation Exception:  “Client found response content type of 'multipart/related".

As I understand I get the following error because the service is using MTOM to send pdf files. Is there any way to fix the web references as it can decode MTOM correctly without error or I should create an decoder for it. And send a request without using web references.

I try to use row response and pass it to MTOM reader

```
 XmlDictionaryReader mtomReader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateMtomReader(response.GetResponseStream() , Encoding.UTF8, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max);
```

But getting another error

> System.Xml.XmlException: Content-Type header for MTOM message not
>   found.

Response example:

```
--MIMEBoundaryurn_uuid_F468164F66D5B7FD071377072332741
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=iso-8859-1; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <0.urn:uuid:F468164F66D5B7FD071377072332742@apache.org>
```

Soap-xml

```
--MIMEBoundaryurn_uuid_F468164F66D5B7FD071377072332741
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <urn:uuid:F468164F66D5B7FD071377072332744@apache.org>
```

PDF binary

```
 --MIMEBoundaryurn_uuid_F468164F66D5B7FD071377072332741--
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems with ASP.NET generated code & settings for ChangeService (Rational Synergy) WSDL file.
I was also receiving the MIME header along with XML message. Assuming that you are using a service reference, I had to modify the web.config file with the following changes

First i had to modify the HttpBinding from basicHttpBinding to webHttpBinding, add behaviors and configure endpoint.

In the config below changes are marked in BOLD

```
<bindings>
  <!--  basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ChangeServiceHttpBinding" messageEncoding="Mtom" />
  </basicHttpBinding  -->
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ChangeServiceHttpBinding" />
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webEndpoint">
      <webHttp defaultBodyStyle="Wrapped" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Xml"
          helpEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>    
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://hostname:port_number/change/webservices/ChangeService" 
            binding="webHttpBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="ChangeServiceHttpBinding"               
            contract="ChangeSynergyService.ChangeService" 
            name="ChangeServiceHttpPort" behaviorConfiguration="webEndpoint" />
</client>
```

Hope this helps